# Is it safe to override the constructor pseudofunction when subclassing builtins?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, subclassing, es6-class

In ES6, we can finally subclass builtins like `Array`:

```
class Bar extends Array {
    ...
}
```

Without doing anything special, the `Array` methods which would normally return `Array` instances will return `Bar` instances when called through a `Bar`, since they look up their constructor function through `Symbol.species`.

Now, say I defined a custom constructor function for `Bar`. Is there *any* guarantee as to *how* static and member methods of `Array` call the constructor they look up through `Symbol.species`? Is it, in short, ever safe to provide a user-defined constructor for a subclass of a builtin like `Array`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any guarantee as to how static and member methods of `Array` call the constructor?

Yes, it's properly specified and nailed down. Specifically, all the prototype methods (`slice`, `concat`, `map`, `filter`) do use the abstract [*ArraySpeciesCreate* algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-arrayspeciescreate) which will call the constructor with a single argument: an integer length. [`Array.of`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-array.of) and [`Array.from`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-array.from) do something very similar, although the latter does not pass a length when it creates an array from an iterator.

`concat`, `slice`, `from` and `of` also do explicitly set the `length` property after assigning the elements, `map` and `filter` do not.

Comment: In the spec, again. Guess I should check there more often!

Comment: TBH, even if they're just 6 methods, their behaviour wrt `length` is surprisingly inconsistent. Maybe I should file an issue.